# Error when deploying contract in geth with truffle ? --> Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I  have deployed a contract in a geth private network by using truffle. I can send transaction via my UI in html / nodejs but i am not able to do a call to retrieve informations. If I do, nothing cames back and i have this error : Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? .

So I am wondering if I did something wrong when deploying my contract or if it's my code the problem.

Here is my index.js :

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
var account;
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((f) => {
 account = f[0];
})

abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"candidate","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"totalVotesFor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"candidate","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"validCandidate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"votesReceived","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"candidateList","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"candidate","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"voteForCandidate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"candidateNames","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]')

contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
contract.options.address = "0x71789831d83d4C8325b324eA9B5fFB27525480b5";
// update this contract address with your contract address

candidates = {"Rama": "candidate-1", "Nick": "candidate-2", "Jose": "candidate-3"}

function voteForCandidate(candidate) {
 candidateName = $("#candidate").val();
 console.log(candidateName);

 contract.methods.voteForCandidate(web3.utils.asciiToHex(candidateName)).send({from: account}).then((f) => {
  let div_id = candidates[candidateName];
  contract.methods.totalVotesFor(web3.utils.asciiToHex(candidateName)).call().then((f) => {
   $("#" + div_id).html(f);
  })
 })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 candidateNames = Object.keys(candidates);

 for(var i=0; i<candidateNames.length; i++) {
 let name = candidateNames[i];

 contract.methods.totalVotesFor(web3.utils.asciiToHex(name)).call().then((f) => {
  $("#" + candidates[name]).html(f);
 })
 }
});
```

here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello World DApp</title>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body class="container">
 <h1>A Simple Hello World Voting Application</h1>
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Candidate</th>
     <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Rama</td>
     <td id="candidate-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Nick</td>
     <td id="candidate-2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Jose</td>
     <td id="candidate-3"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <input type="text" id="candidate" />
 <a href="#" onclick="voteForCandidate()" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</a>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.37/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

here is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;
// We have to specify what version of compiler this code will compile with

contract Voting {
  /* mapping field below is equivalent to an associative array or hash.
  The key of the mapping is candidate name stored as type bytes32 and value is
  an unsigned integer to store the vote count
  */

  mapping (bytes32 => uint256) public votesReceived;

  /* Solidity doesn't let you pass in an array of strings in the constructor (yet).
  We will use an array of bytes32 instead to store the list of candidates
  */

  bytes32[] public candidateList;

  /* This is the constructor which will be called once when you
  deploy the contract to the blockchain. When we deploy the contract,
  we will pass an array of candidates who will be contesting in the election
  */
  constructor(bytes32[] memory candidateNames) public {
    candidateList = candidateNames;
  }

  // This function returns the total votes a candidate has received so far
  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint256) {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }

  // This function increments the vote count for the specified candidate. This
  // is equivalent to casting a vote
  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    votesReceived[candidate] += 1;
  }

  function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {
      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and here is my file for deploying the contract with truffle :

```
var voting = artifacts.require("Voting");
candidateList = ['Rema', 'Nick', 'jose']
module.exports = function(deployer) {

   deployer.deploy(voting,['Rema','Nick','Jose'].map(x => web3.utils.asciiToHex(x)));


};
```

Thanks yall !

Answer (score 1):

In your ABI, you indicate to web3 that function `totalVotesFor` returns a `uint8`:

```
{
    "constant"        : true,
    "inputs"          : [{"name":"candidate","type":"bytes32"}],
    "name"            : "totalVotesFor",
    "outputs"         : [{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
    "payable"         : false,
    "stateMutability" : "view",
    "type"            : "function"
}
```

But in your contract, function `totalVotesFor` returns a `uint256`:

```
function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint256)
```

So the first part of the error (`Returned values aren't valid`) makes sense.

The second part of the error (`did it run Out of Gas?`) is indeed misleading.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer ! I change to 256 in the abi but returning the same error :(

Comment: @oklm: Please indicate in the question, which line in your code throws this error.

Comment: the exact error is web3.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? in line web3.min.js:1

Comment: @oklm: No. In **your code**, please specify which line throws the error. If you don't know, then please debug it and find out.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the first time, how can I find out which line do this ? I think its in the call because when i call the contract function totalvotesfor function in truffle console, it output the same error , i did a mistake when I deployed ?

Comment: @oklm: Don't you know any debug techniques whatsoever? You might have a really hard time making any progress, even after you solve the current problem. In any case, just add a printout after every line of code within the "suspected" area, and find out which is the last line to be executed without an error. The line which comes after that line is where the error occurs.

Comment: Oh ok sorry really tired i wasn't thinking of this type of debug, I was thinking that you were talking about debug the blockchain with some special tools .. anyway I already tried and the only lines that not returning any logs are theses : contract.methods.voteForCandidate(web3.utils.asciiToHex(candidateName)).send({from: account}).then((f) => {
  let div_id = candidates[candidateName];
  contract.methods.totalVotesFor(web3.utils.asciiToHex(candidateName)).call().then((f) => {
   $("#" + div_id).html(f);
  })
 })
}

Comment: sorry I always hit the enter button and send the comment whithout ending ...

Comment: @oklm: Can you put a log inside each one of the callback functions?

Comment: I put console logs inside each one, and got no news from the part i send in the functions i Said , all the others are returning something

Comment: @oklm: Have you placed the log at the beginning of each callback?

Comment: @oklm: BTW, since you've initially started with a valid but wrong ABI (and it is not that "easy" to change it while keeping it valid), my primary suspicion would be that... god knows what contract you've actually deployed, and to what address you've deployed it. I recommend that you rebuild your contract and redeploy it. Then, make sure to use the latest ABI and the latest contract address in your code.